# How to call a function after completion of all requests

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two AJAX requests one after another-

```
var firstResult;
var secondResult;

FirstAjaxrequest({
        callback: function (options, success, response) {
            if(success)
            {
                firstResult = true;
            }
            else
            {
                firstResult = false;
            }
        }    
    });

SecondAjaxrequest({
     callback: function (options, success, response) {
            if(success)
            {
                secondResult= true;
            }
            else
            {
                secondResult= false;
            }
     }    
});

DisplayMessage(); // This function should display a message depending on     
                     FirstResult and secondResult
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could create a variable for each request, signifying a successful request. Change this variable for each request respectively, when a successful request is made, then call your function.

Within your function simply check both variables, if they're both true, then both requests were successful, otherwise at least one was not and the `if()` condition will be false.

```
var firstResult = false,
    secondResult = false;

FirstAjaxrequest({
    callback: function (options, success, response) {
        if(success) {
            firstResult = true;
            DisplayMessage();
        }
    }    
});

SecondAjaxrequest({
    callback: function (options, success, response) {
        if(success) {
            secondResult= true;
            DisplayMessage();
        }
    }    
});

function DisplayMessage(){
    if(firstResult && secondResult){
        //Both requests successful
    } else {
        //Either still waiting for a request to complete
        // or a request was not successful.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he rather want's `DisplayMessage` to be invoked only when both callbacks finished, like if the Ajax Calls were nested

Comment: To generalize, instead of keeping a set of booleans, you could keep a counter. You could also use a "Promise" mechanism to do that for you; that approach encapsulates both the keeping track of completion and also success/failure.

Comment: You could, but I was using the variables that the OP provided, to keep things as simple and understandable as possible.

Comment: @F4r-20 oh, I somehow overread the conditional part of DisplayMessage =) 
+1

Comment: These are simultaneous requests. So I cant use solution given byF4r-20. Also I am not able to get firstResult/secondResult in DisplayMessge(). So basically I want to extcute DisplayMessage() after completion of both requests with firstResult/secondResult values.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better way to do it in EXTJS, but a plain JS solution is

```
var firstResult;
var secondResult;
var reqCount = 2;
var returnedCount = 0;

function isDone () {
    returnedCount++
    if ( returnedCount === reqCount ) {
         console.log(firstResult, secondResult);
    }
}

FirstAjaxrequest({
        callback: function (options, success, response) {
            if(success)
            {
                firstResult = true;
            }
            else
            {
                firstResult = false;
            }
            isDone();
        }    
    });

SecondAjaxrequest({
     callback: function (options, success, response) {
            if(success)
            {
                secondResult= true;
            }
            else
            {
                secondResult= false;
            }
            isDone();
     }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
FirstAjaxrequest({
            callback: function (options, success, response) {
                if(success)
                {
                    firstResult = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    firstResult = false;
                }
                SecondAjaxrequest({
                     callback: function (options, success, response) {
                            if(success)
                            {
                                secondResult= true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                secondResult= false;
                            }
                            DisplayMessage(); // Now we have access to first and second result as the 
                                             //as the second request is within the scope of the first request
                     },
                     scope: this // We can pass the first request to the second request as the context 
                });
            }    
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

After the completion of each request, you should check if the result of the other one is received or not.
Some thing like this:

```
var result1 = null;
var result2 = null;
function DoAjax() {
    $.get(url1, {}, function (data) {
         result1 = data;
         DoSth();
    });
    $.get(url2, {}, function (data) {
         result2 = data;
         DoSth();
    });
}
function DoSth() {
    if(result1 != null && result2 != null) {
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: And I said sth like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Warning: jQuery answer. I'm not sure if `extjs` has similar support for Deferreds and Promises.

This is a perfect opportunity to learn about [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
$.when(firstAjaxrequest(...), secondAjaxrequest(...))
.then(function (firstResult, secondResult) {
    ...
});
```

This assumes your `firstAjaxrequest` and `secondAjaxrequest` functions both return `Deferred` or `Promise` objects, such as those returned by `$.ajax`.